# Appium-Python-client TouchAction class is being deprecated. How do I perform press(), long_press() actions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ui-automation, python-appium

I have a method that allows me to scroll down (android and iOS) on a menu (this works for me since it's a side menu).

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

    def _scroll_down_menu_settings(self, distance=400):
        action = TouchAction(self.driver)
        window_size = self.driver.get_window_size()
        x, y = window_size['width'] / 6, window_size['height'] / 2
        action.press(x=x, y=y).wait(500).move_to(x=x, y=y - distance).release().perform()
```

How can I perform a press (or click?) by coordinates with `ActionChains` so I can perform a scroll down by customized distance?

`TouchAction` class is being deprecated, and the documentation recommends to use `ActionChains`. I've tried to do it with `ActionChain.some_actions()` available in its class, but none of them work for me. For example: `scroll_to_element()`, `scroll_by_amount()`, `scroll_from_origin()` since they are imported as:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`

as opposed to using TouchActions as:

`from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself after all...
So It seems it has to import several other parts in order to mimic what `TouchActions` from Appium was doing (ridiculous). So below is the block of code that can replace my previous block of code using the soon-to-be deprecated `TouchAction` in Appium automation.

```py
def _scroll_down_menu_settings(self, distance=400):
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    window_size = self.driver.get_window_size()
    x, y = window_size['width'] / 6, window_size['height'] / 2
    action.w3c_actions = ActionBuilder(self.driver, mouse=PointerInput(interaction.POINTER_TOUCH, 'touch'))
    action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(x, y)
    action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.click_and_hold()
    action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(x, y - distance)
    action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.release()
    action.w3c_actions.perform()
```